# If$ \{\tau_{\alpha}\} $be a family of topology on $X$ then the smallest topology containing all $\{\tau_{\alpha}\}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, solution-verification

> If $\{\tau_{\alpha}\}$ be a family of topology on $X$ then the smallest topology containing all $\{\tau_{\alpha}\}$

The basic intuition that I have is the smallest topology will be the topology generated by $\cup_{\alpha}\{B_{\alpha}\}$ where $B_{\alpha}$ is the basis of $\tau_{\alpha}$.

Edit 1:I need to prove that it is the smallest topology.

We denote by $\tau$ the topology generated by $\cup \{B_{\alpha}\}$.

We consider $\tau' \subset \tau$ and $\tau'$ containing all the family of topologies .

Then, we know that for each $x \in X$ and each element $B' \in \cup\{B'_{\alpha}\}$ there is an element $B \in \cup\{B_{\alpha}\}$ such that $x \in B \subset B'$.Can we conclude from here that $B'_{\alpha} \subset \cup\{B_{\alpha}\}$?

Since the family of topologies $\{\tau_{\alpha}\}$ is a subset of $\tau'_{\alpha}$ then we can conclude that $\cup\{B_{\alpha}\}  \subset B'_{\alpha}$.

So $\tau=\tau'$.

Is this proof OK? And if it is OK then is my topology  unique?

Is my intuition correct? Also my answer has been without consulting the other answers on the net, it  would be rather helpful if someone points out my mistake as in why this topology will not hold rather than suggesting an answer.

Comment: Your suggestion looks right.

Comment: One choice of basis is the whole topology.  So you could use the topology generated by $\bigcup_\alpha \tau_\alpha$.

Comment: @GEdgar is $\cup_{\alpha}\tau_{\alpha}$ a topology?Consider $\tau_1=\{\phi,\{a\},X\}$ and $\tau_2=\{\phi,\{b\},X\}$.I am not sure whether the union is a topology?

Comment: Not usually a topology. So we need "the topology generated by".

Comment: I think both are same.How do you go about proving it?I am not really convinved with the OP's argument.